# AWS-backup: The provided policy document does not meet the requirements of the specified policy type

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-organizations, aws-backup

the policy document im are providing does not conform to the expected format for the backup policy.

Im trying to use This template.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform:
  - 'AWS::LanguageExtensions'
Parameters:
  pOrgBackupTargetOUs:
    Description: A comma separated list of the AWS Organizations OUs to attach backup policies.
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
  pCentralBackupVaultArn:
    Description: The **ARN** of a centralized AWS Backup Vault that will be the secondary store for all AWS Backups. The defined organization backup policy plans will "copy_to" this vault.
    Type: String
  pCrossAccountBackupRole:
    Description: This is the IAM role name for the cross-account backup role that carries out the backup activities.
    Type: String
  pMemberAccountBackupVault:
    AllowedPattern: ^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]{1,50}$
    ConstraintDescription: The name of the member account Backup vaults. (Name is case sensitive). 
    Type: String
  pTagKey:
    Type: String 
    Description: This is the tag key to assign to resources.
    Default: 'project'
  pTagValue:
    Type: String 
    Description: This is the tag value to assign to resources.
    Default: 'aws-backup'
Resources:
  rOrgDailyBackUpPolicy:
    Type: AWS::Organizations::Policy
    Properties:
      Name: org-daily-backup-policy
      Description: >-
        BackupPolicy for Daily Backup as per the resource selection criteria
      Type: BACKUP_POLICY
      TargetIds: !Ref pOrgBackupTargetOUs
      Content:
        Fn::ToJsonString:
          plans:
            OrgBackupPlanDaily:
              rules:
                OrgDailyBackupRule:
                  schedule_expression:
                    "@@assign": cron(0 19 ? * * *)
                  start_backup_window_minutes:
                    "@@assign": '60'
                  complete_backup_window_minutes:
                    "@@assign": '1200'
                  lifecycle:
                    delete_after_days:
                      "@@assign": '14'
                  target_backup_vault_name:
                    "@@assign": !Ref pMemberAccountBackupVault
                  recovery_point_tags:
                    project:
                      tag_key:
                        "@@assign": !Ref pTagKey
                      tag_value:
                        "@@assign": !Ref pTagValue
                  copy_actions:
                    "<my-central-vault-ARN-hardcoded>":
                      target_backup_vault_arn:
                        "@@assign": !Ref pCentralBackupVaultArn
                      lifecycle:
                        delete_after_days:
                          "@@assign": '14'
              backup_plan_tags:
                project:
                  tag_key:
                     "@@assign": !Ref pTagKey
                  tag_value:
                     "@@assign": !Ref pTagValue
              regions:
                "@@append":
                  - eu-central-1
              selections:
                tags:
                  OrgDailyBackupSelection:
                    iam_role_arn:
                      "@@assign": !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::$account:role/${pCrossAccountBackupRole}'
                    tag_key:
                      "@@assign": 'backup'
                    tag_value:
                      "@@assign":
                        - daily
```

Explanation of code:

Overall, this CloudFormation template creates an AWS backup policy for resources within an AWS Organization, specifying the backup rules and the storage locations for the backup data.

- **rOrgDailyBackUpPolicy** resource of type AWS::Organizations::Policy that creates a backup policy within the specified target OUs.
- **Name** and Description specify the name and description of the backup policy.
  Type specifies the type of policy as BACKUP_POLICY.
- **TargetIds** specifies the AWS Organization OUs to which the policy will be attached.
- **Content** specifies the backup policy plan details using the intrinsic function Fn::ToJsonString, which converts the contents to a JSON-formatted string. This backup plan has the name **OrgBackupPlanDaily** and includes a set of rules that define when and how backups are taken. These rules include scheduling expressions, window duration for backups, and lifecycle details for backup data.
- **backup_plan_tags** and **recovery_point_tags** specify tags to apply to the backup plan and recovery points created by the plan, respectively.
- **regions** specifies the regions in which backups are taken.
- **selections** specifies the resource selection criteria for backups. In this case, it selects resources with the tag backup set to daily.
- **iam_role_arn** specifies the IAM role name for the cross-account backup role that carries out the backup activities.
- **target_backup_vault_name** and target_backup_vault_arn specify the name and ARN of the backup vaults where the backups will be stored. **target_backup_vault_arn** is set to the value of the **pCentralBackupVaultArn** parameter passed to the template.
- **copy_actions** specifies the backup vault where a copy of backups will be stored. This section includes the name of the backup vault, and the lifecycle details for the copied data. The **target_backup_vault_arn** value is hardcoded and not parameterized.

But I am getting an error `The provided policy document does not meet the requirements of the specified policy type.` While trying to create the backup policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault. I was providing the name of the central vault instead of ARN as template parameter.

So make sure that **copy_actions** contains the ARN of the central vault, hardcoded and as parameter.